# Error al querer extraer el año a una propiedad Fecha

Tags: c#

Buenos días:

Cuando quiero extraer el año de una Fecha cuando la Propiedad acepta Nulos me sale error, pero cuando la propiedad no acepta Nulos pasa normal...

```
string Ano = FechaResolucion.Year.ToString();
```

`FechaResolucion` es un campo Date que acepta nulos, proveniente de SQL Server usando Entity Framework.

Gracias.

Comment: Intenta con `string Ano = FechaResolucion.Value.Year.ToString();` se trata de un tipo `Nullable` y por lo tanto para acceder al valor es a través de la propiedad `Value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La propiedad `Year` pertenece a `DateTime`, y no a `Nullable<DateTime>`. Por lo tanto debes primero acceder al `DateTime` para acceder al año. O sea:

```
FechaResolucion.Value.Year
```

Pero antes **debes asegurarte** de que `FechaResolucion` no sea null. Por ejemplo:

```
string Ano = FechaResolucion.HasValue ? FechaResolucion.Value.Year.ToString() : string.Empty;
```

Si estás usando C# 6 o superior (Visual Studio 2015), puedes usar el null-conditional operator:

```
string Ano = FechaResolucion?.Year.ToString();
```

Esto hace que si `FechaResolucion` es null, toda la expresión es null.

Comment: Excelente Andrew.

Comment: Excelente Andrew. Aunque la penúltima linea era   string Ano = actualizar.FechaResolucion.HasValue ? actualizar.FechaResolucion.Value.Year.ToString() : string.Empty;    (sin el Year.HasValue)...jeje    Mil gracias

Comment: Es verdad, sobraba el `Year`, ya lo arreglé. :)